# Using Object.assign() on a doc returned from a mongoose Model query

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose

When using Object.assign() on a document returned from a mongoose model query, the object returns extraneous data which I do not want, and to get the actual document data I need to use doc._doc - whereas without using Object.assign() I have immediate access to the document data (not inside ._doc).

```
UserModel.findOne(query, function(err, doc){

    //this outputs my document data just fine
    console.log(doc);

    //this outputs extraneous data, assigning someProp not to my document data,
    //but to the outer object.
    console.log(Object.assign({}, doc, { someProp: true});

})
```

Here is the result of console.log(doc):

```
{ 
  _id: 5ab5df214869bc4bfc059fed,
  userID: 0,
  verified: false,
  verificationCode: 'vC_10a89847-f640-43fc-94cc-8ea532f5e05c',
  email: 'ee@ee.ee',
  createdAt: 2018-03-24T05:16:17.508Z,
  updatedAt: 2018-03-25T16:57:30.101Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

And here is the result of console.log(Object.assign({}, doc, { someProp: true });

```
{ '$__':
   InternalCache {
     strictMode: true,
     selected: {},
     shardval: undefined,
     saveError: undefined,
     validationError: undefined,
     adhocPaths: undefined,
     removing: undefined,
     inserting: undefined,
     version: undefined,
     getters: {},
     _id: 5ab5df214869bc4bfc059fed,
     populate: undefined,
     populated: undefined,
     wasPopulated: false,
     scope: undefined,
     activePaths: StateMachine { paths: [Object], states: [Object], stateNames: [Array] },
     pathsToScopes: {},
     ownerDocument: undefined,
     fullPath: undefined,
     emitter: EventEmitter { domain: null, _events: {}, _eventsCount: 0, _maxListeners: 0 },
     '$options': true },
  isNew: false,
  errors: undefined,
  _doc:
   { 
     _id: 5ab5df214869bc4bfc059fed,
     userID: 0,
     verified: false,
     verificationCode: 'vC_10a89847-f640-43fc-94cc-8ea532f5e05c',
     email: 'ee@ee.ee',
     createdAt: 2018-03-24T05:16:17.508Z,
     updatedAt: 2018-03-25T16:57:30.101Z,
     __v: 0 },
  '$init': true,
  someProp: true }
```

My question is, why do I need to use doc._doc inside and after using `doc = Object.assign({}, doc._doc, { someProp: true })` to access my document data, but I could access the data properties without `._doc` before using `doc = Object.assign(...)`?

Comment: Before it was probably some model instance, which often have top-level _accessors_ for their attributes. After you do `doc = Object.assign({}, doc)` it's a plain object, which does not have these accessors, or any model prototype method.

Comment: I am struggling to understand this; how does the model instance output just the data inside _doc, and what in Object.assign converts the model instance to a plain object containing these other 'top-level accessors' ?

Comment: I believe console.log uses .toString() and the model instance overrides .toString() to output the ._doc of the top level model instance. To get just the _doc as JSON use doc.toJSON() as defined here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toJSON or toObject. Thanks for helping me with this in that it is a model instance.n.